# Загрузка видео с YouTube

Tags: delphi

Как осуществить просмотр и загрузку видео с YouTube.
Просмотр в программе, загрузку только ролика, формат mp4.
(примерно так как в программе на картинке
http://s017.radikal.ru/i408/1111/9c/ffac4ea3456e.jpg)

Хочу добавить.
Большая просьба не отвечать на вопрос загадками, пожалуйста по подробней и если можно с исходником...

Comment: Просмотр внутри программы? Просмотр страницы или только ролика? Загрузка в каком разрешении?

Comment: Так ли стоит загружать файл, если можно во встроенном браузера показывать embedded видео?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для загрузки надо будет парсить код страницы и смотреть какие ссылки генерируются в коде страницы на тот или иной файл. Когда найдена ссылка на конкретный файл, то загрузить его можно также как и страницу. Попробовать просматривать скачанный файл можно с помощью дельфового TMediaPlayer.

Для загрузки страницы и других файлов можно использовать дельфовым Indy, можно еще ICS или Synapse. Я предпочитаю последную. Примеров в интернете предостаточно.